# Excel sum rounded geometric series

Tags: excel, sum

I'm struggling with how to do this one in Excel.  I want the sum a geometric series using three cells and the ROUNDUP function.  The formula is to sum (a1/(b1^k)) where k goes from 1 to c1.  Without the ROUNDUP() function, I'd use the sum of a geometric series, but I can't figure out how to do it with it.

Comment: Show us what you have without the ROUNDUP function.

Comment: Do you want to ROUNDUP each element of the series or only the final sum??